# How to set gulp autoprefixer that it will be prefix css when I save my project

Tags: css, gulp

I have a gulpfile like this

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename'); 
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss') 
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        /*.pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed' 
        }))*/
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min' 
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/')) 
        .pipe(browserSync.stream()); 
});


gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src"
    });

    gulp.watch('src/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
    gulp.watch("src/index.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('image', function() {
    gulp.src('src/img/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/build/img'));
});

gulp.task('autoprefixer', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/css/*')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%', 'iOS 7'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'image', 'autoprefixer' ]);
```

I would like to prefix my css code when I save my project.
Right now it doesn't work and I have to stop my gulp and then write gulp autoprefixer in the console.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created new gulp task to that, since you already have tasks "sass" and "serve", you could just include autoprefixer into "sass" task, so it would be like:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss') 
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    /*.pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'compressed' 
    }))*/
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min' 
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%', 'iOS 7'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/')) 
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()); 
});
```